# Making a text game and some options are ignored and just end the program

Tags: java

I've been making a text game and finished all the answers, but some don't seem to do anything, it just ends the program. (Already posted this once yesterday in a earlier build and the brackets were the issue) I'm 90% sure it's to do with these brackets { and } but I can't figure out what I did wrong (I'm new to Java sorry ;-;) I'm gonna put the whole code down here because multiple instances of the just not doing anything but ending the program are happening. Sorry for bad formatting because I have not figured out how to do formatting right yet.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Spookster

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        int actionOne, actionTwo, actionThree, actionFour, actionFive, actionSix, actionSeven, actionEight, actionNine, actionTen, actionEleven, actionTwelve;

        System.out.println("You wake up in a metallic room. There is a knife next to you, and there is a door ahead of you.");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 to go to the door, enter 2 to pick up the knife: ");
        actionOne = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (actionOne == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You walk to the door. There is a small window that you could look through.");
            System.out.println("You could also just open the door right there.");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to look through the window, enter 2 to go through the door: ");
            actionTwo = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (actionTwo == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
                System.out.println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            } else if (actionTwo == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
                System.out.println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
                System.out.print("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself: ");
                actionTen = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actionTen == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You dodge his attack and he runs into the door at full speed.");
                    System.out.println("The alien drops dead. You see a control panel and a detonation button.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to try to fly the ship to earth, enter 2 to self destruct the ship: ");
                    actionEleven = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionEleven == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You go to the controls and they seem to work fine. They are easy enough to learn quick.");
                        System.out.println("You fly the ship down to earth and see the whitehouse, and land there.");
                        System.out.println("The president walks out in awe, and you see an alien pull out a gun.");
                        System.out.print("Enter 1 to save the president, enter 2 to stay back: ");
                        actionTwelve = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actionTwelve == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You run to the alien attempting to save the president but he turns to you and fires.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        } else if (actionTwelve == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You stand and watch as the president is shot by the alien.");
                            System.out.println("Suddenly you feel sharp pain in your gut, the alien as fired at you.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        }
                    } else if (actionEleven == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You know this is the right thing to do. Although you will lose your life, so will the aliens.");
                        System.out.println("They are too dangerous to be alive anyways.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU DIED A HEROIC DEATH - BAD ENDING");
                } else if (actionTen ==2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You attempt to defend yourself but the alien stabs you.");
                    System.out.println("As your vision fades to black you can only wish you evaded him.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            }

        } else if (actionOne == 2) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("You pick up the knife and hear something behind you.");
            System.out.println("You blindly throw your hand backwards and realise you killed a tall creature.");
            System.out.println("There is an advanced gun in his hand");
            System.out.print("Enter 1 to pick up the gun, enter 2 to leave it be: ");
            actionThree = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (actionThree == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("You grab the gun and the creature moves, you quickly aim and fire");
                System.out.println("The creature drops dead. You take a look around and notice a corridor.");
                System.out.println("You head down the corridor and it splits.");
                System.out.print("Enter 1 to head left, enter 2 to head right: ");
                actionFour = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actionFour == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You head left. There is a control panel that controls an escape pod");
                    System.out.println("There are two buttons, a blue button and a yellow button.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to press the blue button, enter 2 to press the yellow button: ");
                    actionFive = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionFive == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You press the blue button. The ship begins to shake.");
                        System.out.println("You take your last breath as the ship explodes");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actionFive == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You press the yellow button. The escape pod door opens.");
                        System.out.println("You walk inside and hear something behind you.");
                        System.out.println("There are two switches in an alien language. One must control the door.");
                        System.out.print("Enter 1 to activate the left switch, enter 2 to activate the right switch.");
                        actionSeven = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actionSeven == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You activate the left switch and the hatch closes.");
                            System.out.println("There is only one other switch, you activate it.");
                            System.out.println("The escape pod launches from the ship. On the descent down you see the alien ship come towards earth.");
                            System.out.println("Seconds later the ship is blown to bits. Once you land you are greeted by a govenment agency");
                            System.out.println("They thank you for baiting the ship in, and give you a medal for your accomplishments.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - BAD ENDING");
                        } else if (actionSeven == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You activate the right switch and the escape pod launches into space.");
                            System.out.println("You see the alien bodies fly out of the ship before your eyes pop");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (actionFour == 2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("You head right. There is an armory filled with alien weapons.");
                    System.out.print("Enter 1 to get an alien rifle, enter 2 to leave the weapons and continue down the hall: ");
                    actionSix = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actionSix == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You pick up an alien rifle. It sends off an alarm.");
                        System.out.println("Multiple aliens are rushing down the halls. You pick off a few.");
                        System.out.println("Suddenly you feel pain in your stomache and you drop to the floor.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actionSix == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("You decide it's not worth the risk.");
                        System.out.println("You keep heading down the corridor and find some type of needle filled with liquid.");
                        System.out.print("Enter 1 to inject the liquid into you, enter 2 to leave it: ");
                        actionEight = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actionEight == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You inject the liquid and see your arms and body slowly vanish.");
                            System.out.println("It seems you injected yourself with a cloaking syrum.");
                            System.out.println("Seconds later an alien comes in. It growls then moves off looking for you.");
                            System.out.println("Heading down the corridor you see another alien, this one looks different.");
                            System.out.println("It wears a cloak and crown, and looks to be of high status.");
                            System.out.print("Enter 1 to attempt to communicate, enter 2 to remain silent: ");
                            actionNine = keyboard.nextInt();
                            if (actionNine == 1) {
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("You speak in english 'Why am I here?!'");
                                System.out.println("To your surprise the alien responds in English");
                                System.out.println("He says 'We were testing humans, you seem like a smart one");
                                System.out.println("He says 'I would like to take you back to our home system.'");
                                System.out.println("He says 'After seeing what you can do, I believe you could help us in our galactic republic'");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("1 Year Later");
                                System.out.println("You are now part of a galactic republic lightyears away. You have forgotten your old life.");
                                System.out.println("Something has made you forget it, but that doesn't matter now. You are a part of their military.");
                                System.out.println("You don't question their motives, because you have no reason to.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - GOOD ENDING");
                            } else if (actionNine == 2) {
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("You suddenly feel weak. A crunching feeling is in your body.");
                                System.out.println("It seems the alien knew you were there. He is much more powerful than the rest.");
                                System.out.println("Your insides begin to hurt until blood bursts from your stomach, you fall to the ground.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                            }
                        } else if (actionEight == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You leave the needle there.");
                            System.out.println("Suddenly a blade pierces through you. An alien has sneaked up on you.");
                            System.out.println("As your vision fades to black, you feel absolute terror.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (actionThree == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("The creature becomes conscious and aims the gun at you, you stand in fear.");
                System.out.println("Suddenly you hear a loud noise and everything is black.");
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: sorry that it's very messy by the way, I try my best to keep it neat but it goes downhill fast haha.

Comment: Let your IDE format the code for you. You have some places here where you got the brackets wrong but your indentation confuses you. When your IDE formats it, you'll see that there are places where you else-if on a variable that should have been one level to the left - and that means a bracket is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To format your code, press `Ctrl-Shift-F` (or `CMD`). Also, typing `2` for option 1 doesn't do anything because your code reads (pseudocode):

```
if option1 = 1:
    ...
<end>
```

You need to reformat the if statements. Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Spookster

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] actions = new int[6];
        System.out
                .println("You wake up in a metallic room. There is a knife next to you, and there is a door ahead of you.");
        System.out
                .print("Enter 1 to go to the door, enter 2 to pick up the knife: ");
        actions[0] = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (actions[0] == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out
                    .println("You walk to the door. There is a small window that you could look through.");
            System.out
                    .println("You could also just open the door right there.");
            System.out
                    .print("Enter 1 to look through the window, enter 2 to go through the door: ");
            actions[1] = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (actions[1] == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out
                        .println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
                System.out
                        .println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            } else if (actions[1] == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out
                        .println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
                System.out
                        .println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
                System.out
                        .print("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself: ");
                actions[2] = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actions[2] == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out
                            .println("You dodge his attack and he runs into the door at full speed.");
                    System.out
                            .println("The alien drops dead. You see a control panel and a detonation button.");
                    System.out
                            .print("Enter 1 to try to fly the ship to earth, enter 2 to self destruct the ship: ");
                    actions[3] = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actions[3] == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("You go to the controls and they seem to work fine. They are easy enough to learn quick.");
                        System.out
                                .println("You fly the ship down to earth and see the White House, and land there.");
                        System.out
                                .println("The president walks out in awe, and you see an alien pull out a gun.");
                        System.out
                                .print("Enter 1 to save the president, enter 2 to stay back: ");
                        actions[4] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actions[4] == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out
                                    .println("You run to the alien attempting to save the president but he turns to you and fires.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        } else if (actions[4] == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out
                                    .println("You stand and watch as the president is shot by the alien.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("Suddenly you feel sharp pain in your gut, the alien has fired at you.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        }
                    } else if (actions[3] == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("You know this is the right thing to do. Although you will lose your life, so will the aliens.");
                        System.out
                                .println("They are too dangerous to be alive anyways.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("YOU DIED A HEROIC DEATH - BAD ENDING");
                    }
                } else if (actions[2] == 2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out
                            .println("You attempt to defend yourself but the alien stabs you.");
                    System.out
                            .println("As your vision fades to black you can only wish you evaded him.");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                }
            }
        } else if (actions[0] == 2) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out
                    .println("You pick up the knife and hear something behind you.");
            System.out
                    .println("You blindly throw your hand backwards and realise you killed a tall creature.");
            System.out.println("There is an advanced gun in his hand");
            System.out
                    .print("Enter 1 to pick up the gun, enter 2 to leave it be: ");
            actions[1] = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (actions[1] == 1) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out
                        .println("You grab the gun and the creature moves, you quickly aim and fire");
                System.out
                        .println("The creature drops dead. You take a look around and notice a corridor.");
                System.out.println("You head down the corridor and it splits.");
                System.out
                        .print("Enter 1 to head left, enter 2 to head right: ");
                actions[2] = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (actions[2] == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out
                            .println("You head left. There is a control panel that controls an escape pod");
                    System.out
                            .println("There are two buttons, a blue button and a yellow button.");
                    System.out
                            .print("Enter 1 to press the blue button, enter 2 to press the yellow button: ");
                    actions[3] = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actions[3] == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("You press the blue button. The ship begins to shake.");
                        System.out
                                .println("You take your last breath as the ship explodes");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actions[3] == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("You press the yellow button. The escape pod door opens.");
                        System.out
                                .println("You walk inside and hear something behind you.");
                        System.out
                                .println("There are two switches in an alien language. One must control the door.");
                        System.out
                                .print("Enter 1 to activate the left switch, enter 2 to activate the right switch.");
                        actions[5] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actions[5] == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out
                                    .println("You activate the left switch and the hatch closes.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("There is only one other switch, you activate it.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("The escape pod launches from the ship. On the descent down you see the alien ship come towards earth.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("Seconds later the ship is blown to bits. Once you land you are greeted by a govenment agency");
                            System.out
                                    .println("They thank you for baiting the ship in, and give you a medal for your accomplishments.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU SURVIVED - BAD ENDING");
                        } else if (actions[5] == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out
                                    .println("You activate the right switch and the escape pod launches into space.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("You see the alien bodies fly out of the ship before your eyes pop");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (actions[2] == 2) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out
                            .println("You head right. There is an armory filled with alien weapons.");
                    System.out
                            .print("Enter 1 to get an alien rifle, enter 2 to leave the weapons and continue down the hall: ");
                    actions[3] = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (actions[3] == 1) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("You pick up an alien rifle. It sends off an alarm.");
                        System.out
                                .println("Multiple aliens are rushing down the halls. You pick off a few.");
                        System.out
                                .println("Suddenly you feel pain in your stomache and you drop to the floor.");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                    } else if (actions[3] == 2) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        System.out
                                .println("You decide it's not worth the risk.");
                        System.out
                                .println("You keep heading down the corridor and find some type of needle filled with liquid.");
                        System.out
                                .print("Enter 1 to inject the liquid into you, enter 2 to leave it: ");
                        actions[4] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (actions[4] == 1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out
                                    .println("You inject the liquid and see your arms and body slowly vanish.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("It seems you injected yourself with a cloaking syrum.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("Seconds later an alien comes in. It growls then moves off looking for you.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("Heading down the corridor you see another alien, this one looks different.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("It wears a cloak and crown, and looks to be of high status.");
                            System.out
                                    .print("Enter 1 to attempt to communicate, enter 2 to remain silent: ");
                            actions[5] = keyboard.nextInt();
                            if (actions[5] == 1) {
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out
                                        .println("You speak in english 'Why am I here?!'");
                                System.out
                                        .println("To your surprise the alien responds in English");
                                System.out
                                        .println("He says 'We were testing humans, you seem like a smart one");
                                System.out
                                        .println("He says 'I would like to take you back to our home system.'");
                                System.out
                                        .println("He says 'After seeing what you can do, I believe you could help us in our galactic republic'");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("1 Year Later");
                                System.out
                                        .println("You are now part of a galactic republic lightyears away. You have forgotten your old life.");
                                System.out
                                        .println("Something has made you forget it, but that doesn't matter now. You are a part of their military.");
                                System.out
                                        .println("You don't question their motives, because you have no reason to.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out
                                        .println("YOU SURVIVED - GOOD ENDING");
                            } else if (actions[5] == 2) {
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out
                                        .println("You suddenly feel weak. A crunching feeling is in your body.");
                                System.out
                                        .println("It seems the alien knew you were there. He is much more powerful than the rest.");
                                System.out
                                        .println("Your insides begin to hurt until blood bursts from your stomach, you fall to the ground.");
                                System.out.println(" ");
                                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
                            }
                        } else if (actions[4] == 2) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println("You leave the needle there.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("Suddenly a blade pierces through you. An alien has sneaked up on you.");
                            System.out
                                    .println("As your vision fades to black, you feel absolute terror.");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (actions[1] == 2) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out
                        .println("The creature becomes conscious and aims the gun at you, you stand in fear.");
                System.out
                        .println("Suddenly you hear a loud noise and everything is black.");
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I stored all of the variables in an array, and reduced your variable count from 12 to only 6.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it with the current way I have it? I know it's messy but this is for a computer science class, and we havn't learned arrays yet, I'm 90% sure it's a { and } problem but I just can't figure out how to use them.

Comment: It is a { and } problem. Actually, everything will work if you cut the `else if (actionOne...)` block out of the program and paste it one line down, so from:

`} else if (...) {`

Comment: Could you show me an example? Kinda confused on what you mean haha. @James Smith

Answer (score 0):

In solving problems of this type you should use debugger to solve your problem.

[How to debug in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

[How to debug in intelliJ.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debugging-your-first-java-application.html)

Familiarization with this will help you solve not only this problem but many other more complex cases.

Comment: i use textpad, is there a way to do it in there?

Comment: @ZachThePwn I recommend you get eclipse, which allows you to debug, format code, compile and execute code all from the same interface. Go to https://eclipse.org/downloads/